# Using encodeURIComponent in JavaScript to encode URL variable, but then decode to write?

Tags: javascript, xml, netsuite, encodeuricomponent

I've got a weird situation where I'm trying to dynamically construct a URL string in an XML document using JavaScript. I've figured out how to use encodeURIComponent to assemble my URL parameters using ampersands in a string and construct to the URL that I need. However, I need to write the URL to the page as a decoded string because otherwise, visiting that URL doesn't execute the actions I need to correctly. The whole document is constructed in JavaScript, so it has to be in a JavaScript environment.

For instance, I have the following URL that I'm able to assemble in order for the XML to render correctly:

http://www.myurl.com/product-name?itemcolor=2%26size=7

However, I need to turn it back into this as a link in the XML doc:

http://www.myurl.com/product-name?itemcolor=2&size=7

Is that possible? Does that make sense?

Here's my code snippet so far:

```
var baseURL = 'http://myurl.com', urlappend = '', colorid, sizeid;

function getVariants(item) {
    variants = '<variant>';
        if ("custitem109" in item['columns']){
            colorid = item['columns']['custitem109']['internalid'];
            urlappend += '?itemcolor=' + colorid;
        }
        if ("custitem110" in item['columns']){
            sizeid = item['columns']['custitem110']['internalid'];
            urlappend +=  colorid ? encodeURIComponent('&') + 'size=' + sizeid : '?size=' + sizeid;
        }

        if (typeof item['columns']['urlcomponent'] !== 'undefined' && urlappend !== '') {
            variants += '<action_url>' + baseURL + '/' + item['columns']['urlcomponent'] + urlappend + '></action_url>';
        }

    variants += '</variant>';
    return variants;
}
```

(this function gets looped through multiple times to construct a portion of the XML feed)

This is a NetSuite suitelet if that makes any difference or if anyone has any question as to why this all has to be in a JS environment.

Any help provided would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Typically, you would encode everything after the '?', and then you can use decodeURIComponent() to decode the portion of the string after the '?' on the flip side.

Comment: What do you mean by "*in order for the XML to render correctly*"?

Comment: It looks like you've confused percent encoding with XML encoding. Please don't write your own encoding functions when there are many tested libraries available that will do what you're after correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what you want to do is construct your URLs properly and then xml escape them.

e.g:

```
http://www.myurl.com/product-name?itemcolor=2&size=7
```

becomes

```
http://www.myurl.com/product-name?itemcolor=2&amp;size=7
```

Any free text should be run through nlapEscapeXML

```
nlapiEscapeXML('http://www.myurl.com/product-name?itemcolor=2&size=7');
```

Comment: Holy crap. Someone with NetSuite experience??? I feel like I just found a unicorn. This totally did the trick. I didn't even need the first encodeURIComponent(). Leave it to NetSuite...

Comment: I think there are actually a few of us here with a fair bit of NetSuite experience.  If this worked for you it would be great to mark this as an accepted answer